# React and ECMA6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using ECMA6 classe and React, but running into a situation where exceptions in the `render()` method of a nested component don't get reported.

Any ideas?

For instance, this won't report an exception:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    foo; // Throws exception, "foo is undefined"
  }
}

class Demo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Child />
  }
}
```

Comment: you might to to define foo first, perhaps before your "Child" component? or maybe you defined it somewhere, is this your complete code?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and I see `Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined` as expected. Did you remember to render Demo as the root component with `React.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('page'));` or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

The function render need to return somethings. There is no return in your render  function and foo needs to be declared somewhere.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let foo = <span>HelloWorld</span>;
    return foo; // foo is now defined
  }
}

class Demo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Child />
  }
}
```